# What does for loop with [ ] in python do?

Tags: python, loops, csv

The below snippet of code has a for loop with csv file names inside the [] brackets.

```
TRAIN_CSV = './train1.csv' # this comtains 100 entries
TEST_CSV = './test1.csv' # this contains 50 entries
train_df = pd.read_csv(TRAIN_CSV)
test_df = pd.read_csv(TEST_CSV)

for dataset in [train_df, test_df]:   # what does this mean here
     do something
```

What does the for loop do here when supplied with the csv filenames in the [] brackets ?

Comment: How about https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: The [ ] above contains the .csv files. So is it same as the one which the link points to ?

Comment: This syntax is called "sequence unpacking", might be easier to google for

Comment: @Arpit I think the question is mainly due to a confusion about the inline expression of the list, rather than about looping through lists in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the brackets mean a list. So you are looping through a list defined only by the two elements `train_df` and `test_df`.

Comment: here train_df and test_df is loaded with a .csv file. So what does the loop do here ?

Comment: It assigns the contents of the csv-files to the loop-variable `dataset`.